# Why is my hide() and show() not working even without error in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a function that will show the other content and hide the recent content. But when I am clicking the submit input it's not working. I tried to use anchor tag and button tag and it has the same output.

html:

```js
$(function(){
            $('.btn .button').on('click', function(){
                $('.container').show()
                $('.container-two').hide()

            })
        })
```

```css
* {
    text-decoration: none;
}

body {
    background: #8390A2;
}

.student {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.form .student div {
    padding: 10px;
}

.form .student div input {
    background: #f1f5f9;
    margin-top: 5px;
    height: 20px;
}

.student-name {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}
.form .student-name div {
    padding: 10px;
}

.form .student-name div input {
    background: #f1f5f9;
    margin-top: 5px;
    height: 20px;
}

.title-header {
    border-top-right-radius: 10%;
    border-top-left-radius: 10%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    height: 40px;
    background: #efefef;
}

.title-header h3 {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 9px;
}

.form form div .info {
    position: relative;
}


.form .info label {
    position: absolute;
    color: grey;
    pointer-events: none;
    top: 36px;
    left: 15px;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.form .info input:focus ~ label {
    transform: translateY(-20px);
    color: black;
}

.form .info input {
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.form .student div:first-child input {
    width: 95%;
}

.form .info input:focus {
    border-color: #4CCEE8;
}

.form .btn {
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 50px;
    right: 36.5%;
}

.form .btn input,
.form-two .btn input {
    border-radius: 15px;
    outline: none;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
}

.form-two .address div {
    padding: 10px;
}

.address .info-two {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.form-two .student-info div {
    padding: 10px;
}

.form-two .student-info div input {
    background: #f1f5f9;
    margin-top: 5px;
    height: 20px;
}

.form-two .address div input {
    background: #f1f5f9;
    margin-top: 5px;
    height: 20px;
}

.form-two .student-info div input {
    background: #f1f5f9;
    margin-top: 5px;
    height: 20px;
}

.form-two form div .info {
    position: relative;
}


.form-two .info label {
    position: absolute;
    color: grey;
    pointer-events: none;
    top: 36px;
    left: 15px;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.form-two .info input:focus ~ label {
    transform: translateY(-20px);
    color: black;
}

.form-two .info input {
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.form-two .address div:first-child input {
    width: 95%;
}

.form-two .address div:last-child div {
    padding-left: 1px;
}

.form-two .address div:last-child div label {
    left: 8px;
}

.form-two .info input:focus {
    border-color: #4CCEE8;
}

.form-two .btn {
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 14px;
    right: 36.5%;
}

.active {
    display: none;
}

main {
    border-radius: 1%;
    background: #f1f5f9;
    width: 27rem;
    min-height: 30rem;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 13rem;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
}

form h4 {
    margin: 10px;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 1366px) {
    main {
    background: #f1f5f9;
    width: 27rem;
    min-height: 30rem;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 5rem;
    }   
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <main>
            <div class="form">
                <div class="title-header">
                    <h3>Personal Data Information</h3>
                </div>
                <form action="" method="POST">
                    <div class="student">
                        <div class="info">
                            
                            <input type="text" name="Program">
                            <label>Program</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="info">
                            
                            <input type="text" name="Student #">
                            <label>Student #</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <h4>Student Name</h4>
                    <div class="student-name">
                        <div class="info">
                            
                            <input type="text" name="Surname" id="surname">
                            <label>Surname</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="info">
                            
                            <input type="text" name="Given Name" id="givenname">
                            <label>Given Name</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="info">
                            
                            <input type="text" name="Middle Name" id="middlename">
                            <label>Middle Name</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="info">
                            
                            <input type="text" name="Auxillary Name" id="auxillaryname">
                            <label>Auxillary Name</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Continue" class="button">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>

    <div class="container-two active">
        <main>
            <div class="form-two">
                <div class="title-header">
                    <h3>Personal Data Information</h3>
                </div>
                <form action="" method="POST">
                    <h4>Address</h4>
                    <div class="address">
                        <div class="info">
                            
                            <input type="text" name="City Address">
                            <label>City Address</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="info-two" style="padding: 0px;">
                            <div class="info">
                                
                                <input type="text" name="Student #" style="width: 70%;">
                                <label>Zip Code</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="info">
                                
                                <input type="text" name="Student #" style="width: 70%;">
                                <label>Tel no.</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="info">
                            
                            <input type="email" name="Student #" style="width: 95%;">
                            <label>Email Address</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="info">
                            
                            <input type="text" name="City Address" style="width: 95%;">
                            <label>Home Address</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="info">
                                
                            <input type="text" name="Student #" style="width: 34%;">
                            <label>Zip Code</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Continue">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

I tried to use `addClass()` and `removeClass()`, also `css()` but nothing happens. I also find an answer but nothing like my problem.

Comment: What's the purpose of a "submit" button?

Comment: Test your page with the browser "Network" developer tool open.

Comment: @Andreas, to go to another container. I tried to use anchor tag and button tag but nothing happens.

Comment: @pickledrick not the purpose of *your* submit button, but generally what would a *submit* button do?  There's a clue in the name...

Comment: @AdrienLAMOTTE there's two buttons, the first has the class `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Continue" class="button">`

Comment: @freedomn-m, to submit a data.

Comment: Change `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Continue" class="button">` to `<button type='button' class="button">Continue</button>`

Comment: Exactly, your button is submitting your form and thus reloading the page (after your script has run).  Reloading the page restores it to the original - ie with `container` still showing - so you *think* it's doing nothing, but if you watch closely and watch the network tab, you'll see what it's *actually* doing.

Comment: All the wrong guesses should be removed, Andreas already found the problem. You can't submit a form and at the same time stay on the same page. Either no submit at all like @freedomn-m suggested, or prevent default submit behaviour using `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: @freedomn-m, nothing happens. I tried that before.

Comment: Ok, add `return false` at the end of your `.on("click", function () { _your code__ ; return false; })` (or `preventDefault()` as the edit in the comment above)

Comment: You also have your show/hide around the wrong way - you want to hide the first container and show the second: https://jsfiddle.net/3wtcLa2d/

Comment: @freedomn-m prevent default submit behaviour must be attached to submit event listener `$('.form').on('submit', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });`

Comment: @freedomn-m, the `<button type='button' class="button">Continue</button>` works fine now. sorry to forgot that I changed the hide and show to addclass and removeclass.

Comment: My code works fine now. thank you for the answers and I learned from all your suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: @DanielW. no - if you prevent default of the click event it doesn't fire the default click event and it's the default click event which *triggers* the submit event.  It *can* be attached to the form submit, but there's no need for a form submit to be cancelled in this case as there's no need for a form submit.  https://jsfiddle.net/3wtcLa2d/1/

Comment: @freedomn-m but it doesn't prevent from hitting enter and submitting. The whole onclick is wrong, you must use onsubmit.

Comment: @DanielW. good call - all the better reason to not use `<button type="submit"` (or `input type=submit` and use the correct semantic DOM element - ie `<button type="button"`.   However, it appears in Chrome at least that pressing enter in a form still goes via the submit button's click event (for both button and input type=submit) see: https://jsfiddle.net/3wtcLa2d/2/

Comment: @freedomn-m it's normal behaviour, you can submit any form without a submit button. That's why onclick is wrong here anyways. But I also agree that a normal button is better than a submit button here!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, change the first submit type input to a button.
Instead of `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Continue" class="button">`
Should be `<button class="button" type="button">Continue</button>`
This will prevent the form submission, and add the missing "button" class to the button.

Then modify the jquery code like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('.btn .button').on('click', function(e){
    $('.container').hide()
    $('.container-two').show()
  })
})
```

My answer was based on the assumption that you want to show the second container after pressing the first "continue" button.

```js
$(function(){
  $('.btn .button').on('click', function(e){
    $('.container').hide();
    $('.container-two').show();
  });
});
```

```css
* {
    text-decoration: none;
}

body {
    background: #8390A2;
}

.student {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.form .student div {
    padding: 10px;
}

.form .student div input {
    background: #f1f5f9;
    margin-top: 5px;
    height: 20px;
}

.student-name {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}
.form .student-name div {
    padding: 10px;
}

.form .student-name div input {
    background: #f1f5f9;
    margin-top: 5px;
    height: 20px;
}

.title-header {
    border-top-right-radius: 10%;
    border-top-left-radius: 10%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    height: 40px;
    background: #efefef;
}

.title-header h3 {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 9px;
}

.form form div .info {
    position: relative;
}


.form .info label {
    position: absolute;
    color: grey;
    pointer-events: none;
    top: 36px;
    left: 15px;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.form .info input:focus ~ label {
    transform: translateY(-20px);
    color: black;
}

.form .info input {
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.form .student div:first-child input {
    width: 95%;
}

.form .info input:focus {
    border-color: #4CCEE8;
}

.form .btn {
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 50px;
    right: 36.5%;
}

.form .btn input,
.form-two .btn input {
    border-radius: 15px;
    outline: none;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
}

.form-two .address div {
    padding: 10px;
}

.address .info-two {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.form-two .student-info div {
    padding: 10px;
}

.form-two .student-info div input {
    background: #f1f5f9;
    margin-top: 5px;
    height: 20px;
}

.form-two .address div input {
    background: #f1f5f9;
    margin-top: 5px;
    height: 20px;
}

.form-two .student-info div input {
    background: #f1f5f9;
    margin-top: 5px;
    height: 20px;
}

.form-two form div .info {
    position: relative;
}


.form-two .info label {
    position: absolute;
    color: grey;
    pointer-events: none;
    top: 36px;
    left: 15px;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.form-two .info input:focus ~ label {
    transform: translateY(-20px);
    color: black;
}

.form-two .info input {
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.form-two .address div:first-child input {
    width: 95%;
}

.form-two .address div:last-child div {
    padding-left: 1px;
}

.form-two .address div:last-child div label {
    left: 8px;
}

.form-two .info input:focus {
    border-color: #4CCEE8;
}

.form-two .btn {
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 14px;
    right: 36.5%;
}

.active {
    display: none;
}

main {
    border-radius: 1%;
    background: #f1f5f9;
    width: 27rem;
    min-height: 30rem;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 13rem;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
}

form h4 {
    margin: 10px;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 1366px) {
    main {
    background: #f1f5f9;
    width: 27rem;
    min-height: 30rem;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 5rem;
    }   
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <main>
            <div class="form">
                <div class="title-header">
                    <h3>Personal Data Information 1</h3>
                </div>
                <form action="" method="POST">
                    <div class="student">
                        <div class="info">
                            
                            <input type="text" name="Program">
                            <label>Program</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="info">
                            
                            <input type="text" name="Student #">
                            <label>Student #</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <h4>Student Name</h4>
                    <div class="student-name">
                        <div class="info">
                            
                            <input type="text" name="Surname" id="surname">
                            <label>Surname</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="info">
                            
                            <input type="text" name="Given Name" id="givenname">
                            <label>Given Name</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="info">
                            
                            <input type="text" name="Middle Name" id="middlename">
                            <label>Middle Name</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="info">
                            
                            <input type="text" name="Auxillary Name" id="auxillaryname">
                            <label>Auxillary Name</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn">
                    <button class="button" type="button">Continue</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>

    <div class="container-two active">
        <main>
            <div class="form-two">
                <div class="title-header">
                    <h3>Personal Data Information 2</h3>
                </div>
                <form action="" method="POST">
                    <h4>Address</h4>
                    <div class="address">
                        <div class="info">
                            
                            <input type="text" name="City Address">
                            <label>City Address</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="info-two" style="padding: 0px;">
                            <div class="info">
                                
                                <input type="text" name="Student #" style="width: 70%;">
                                <label>Zip Code</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="info">
                                
                                <input type="text" name="Student #" style="width: 70%;">
                                <label>Tel no.</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="info">
                            
                            <input type="email" name="Student #" style="width: 95%;">
                            <label>Email Address</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="info">
                            
                            <input type="text" name="City Address" style="width: 95%;">
                            <label>Home Address</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="info">
                                
                            <input type="text" name="Student #" style="width: 34%;">
                            <label>Zip Code</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Continue">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I copied and pasted the code to [codepen](https://codepen.io/pen/) and found that he is trying to show the div which is already visible and trying to hide the div which is already hidden, so replaced the `hide()` and `show()` with each other.

prevent the default submit event and add `hide()` and `show()` on correct `divs`

```
$(function(){
  $('.btn .button').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.container').hide()
    $('.container-two').show()
  })
})
```

Comment: Consider leaving a comment with your answer explaining the OP why this could solve the problems, Code examples are rarely useful on it's own

Comment: I copied and pasted the code to [codepen](https://codepen.io/pen/) and found that he is trying to show the div which is already visible and trying to hide the div which is already hidden, so replaced the `hide()` and `show()` with each other

Comment: Please, edit your answer to add description instead of a comment.